# Applying attribute to SVG using JS prompts 'this.textBox.style is undefined'. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm using the following code to draw an SVG text box, and then change its text anchor attribute to 'left' as it defaults to center and that's nasty.

The text generates correctly, but when I add this second line I get the error 'this.textBox.style is undefined' in my error console.

Here's my code:

```
    RenderTextBox:function()
{
    // Render Text
    this.textBox = paper.text(this.x, this.y, this.htmlText);
    this.textBox.style.textAnchor="left";
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is

```
this.textBox.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start');
```

(or, since it looks like you're using Raphael)

```
this.textBox.attr( 'text-anchor', 'start' );
```

The valid values for `text-anchor` are `start`, `middle`, `end`, and `inherit`

Comment: Perfect! For some reason I couldn't find a reliable list of values for that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it using bracket notation:

```
    this.textBox.style['text-anchor'] = "left";
```

This way you don't actually have to make a function call.